# Serialize xml with equal default and named namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I know that it doesn't look like best practice but I need to generate xml with same namespaces

for example:

```
<ns1:root xsi:schemaLocation=""http://schemalocation""
xmlns:ns1=""http://schema""
xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
xmlns=""http://schema"">
...
</ns1:root>
```

I also added namespaces to serializer:

```
var xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("ns1", "http://schema");
xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add(string.Empty, "http://schema");
```

And this is class itself:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "request", Namespace = "http://schema")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Request 
    {
        [XmlAttributeAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
        public string SchemaLocation
        {
            get { return _schemaLocation; }
            set { _schemaLocation = value; }
        }

        ...

        private string _schemaLocation = "http://schemalocation";   }
```

So everything is great but default xmlns isn't in generated xml.
I've also played with XmlWriterSettings with no result.
Have anybody ideas how to do it without string replacement?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default namespace is set based on which namespace you use to add the XML fragment e.g.

```
XNamespace defaultNs = @"http://schema";
var result = new XDocument(new XElement(defaultNs + "root"));
```

Would produce the following output:

```
<rootNode xmlns="http://schema">
</rootNode>
```

So all you have to do is add your other named ones to the document i.e.

```
XNamespace defaultNs = @"http://schema";
var root = new XElement(defaultNs + "root",
    new XAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://schemaLocation"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns1", defaultNs"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's a solution, but I need to use xmlserialization from attributed class to xml and using one more object (XDocument) is not good especially when you have big xml. Do you know hot to avoid it?